# How can I turn off Chrome Sync (using my G Suite account) without losing my profile?

Tags: google-chrome, google-workspace

If I press `Turn off` for Sync, Chrome says:

[image: Turn off sync warning]

and deletes the entire profile if I proceed with `Clear and continue`.  I would like to keep my entire profile, not just the bookmarks (which I could export and import).  How can I override Chrome's intentions here and preserve my browser profile?

Answer (score 0):

Quit Chrome.

Run `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences` through a JSON [prettifier/indenter](https://github.com/ludios/quickmunge/blob/master/bin/pretty-json).

Remove the `"google"` and `"account_info"` keys from the top-level object.